# How to create graph in Plone?

Tags: python, plone

How to create graph in Plone ?.
I am customizing Bika Lims. I need to create graph in test result report. I saw there is a feature in Bike to show QC result in graph but I did not get the python code. 
Can any one let me know which library is using in Plone / Bike to show the graph and how to use it in custom code?.

Comment: The best place to ask for Plone help is in the Plone forum, at community.plone.org but in this case because you're asking about how to graph Bika data you're better off asking for Bika support; see https://www.bikalims.org/support-and-service-provision

Comment: Thanks, I have done it by using Pygal module.